# filter spark dataframe using udf

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a student dataframe:

```
var student = Seq(("h123","078","Ryan"),("h789","078","John"),("h456","ad0","Mike")).toDF("id","div","name")
```

now I want to filter `student` on `div` column based on some logic, for this example assume only `078` value should be present.

For this, I have a `udf` defined as:

```
val filterudf = udf((div: String) => div == "078")
```

currently, I am using following approach to get my work done

```
val allowedDivs = student.select(col("div")).distinct().filter(filterudf(col("div")))
                         .collectAsList().asScala.map(row => row.getAs[String](0)).toList
val resultDF = student.filter(col("div").isInCollection(allowedDivs))
```

The actual table where I have to apply this filter is huge and in order to improve the performance I want to use `spark.sql` query to get benefit from codgen and other Tungsten optimizations.

This is want I have come to, but this query is not working

```
filterudf.registerTemplate("filterudf")
val resultDF = spark.sql("select * from student where div in (filterudf(select distinct div from student).div)")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: only "078" is for this example and normally you are going to have more codes? Why you are first selecting all distinct divs and then filtering them with udf, i have a feeling that it could be just select with where to get only students with desired divs

Comment: I have to call another service with div as a parameter (this will be happening in filterudf) thats why I am selecting distinct so that I have to call that service least possible times. You can assume that actual student table will have 10000 rows with possibly 15-20 distinct `div` values.